# Rollback or reverse a table analyze in Postgresql

Tags: postgresql

Using Postgresql, the syntax for a table analyze is very simply:

> `ANALYZE <TABLE_NAME>`

However, is there a means to reverse an analyze?

In oracle databases you can insert the statistics created into a table and then delete them, export them, import them into other databases etc.

My worry is running an analyze and then needing to revert that change.

It seems there is no way to acheive this. Can anyone comment on that?

Thanks.

Comment: "*My worry is running an analyze and then needing to revert that change*" why would you *need* to do that?

Comment: On the off chance that any new plan is less optimal or to revert a test instance back to a prior state easily

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no support in PostgreSQL for overriding statistics other than `n_distinct`, and there is no support for removing table statistics.

You can influence the granularity of the statistics by using `ALTER TABLE ... SET STATISTICS`, and there are extended statistics for cross-column considerations.

Don't worry. PostgreSQL users have more trust in their optimizer than Oracle users.

Answer (score 0):

It is not supported, but you can do it by (as a superuser):

```
 delete from pg_statistic where starelid='public.victim'::regclass;
```

The only time I've needed to do this other than for testing purposes is after analyzing a foreign table, and in that case the supported option would be to drop the foreign table and recreate it (but that can be annoying if there a cascade of views depending on it)